# Should we appcelerate [appc]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I noticed that [Rene Pot](https://stackoverflow.com/u/249710) just created lots of new one-off tags:

1. [appc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appc)
2. [appc-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appc-windows)
3. [appc-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appc-studio)
4. [appc-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appc-cli)
5. [appc-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appc-ios)
6. [appc-ti](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appc-ti)
7. [appc-alloy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appc-alloy)
8. [appc-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appc-android)
9. [appc-oss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appc-oss)

None of the tags has caught on yet, or has a wiki.

These tags all seem to be related with [appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcelerator), but the names of them don't make that very apparent. I myself am not familiar with appcelerator, but do we really need these tags?

Should something be done with these?

- Make them all synonyms of [appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcelerator)
- Rename them to `appcelerator-*` instead of `appc-*` *(This would be my choice)*
- Just burn them

Comment: Maybe: should we appcelerate appc?

Comment: @T3H40 Perfect :) I just edited the post

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Jojodmo, we have been a bit to eager indeed. We appreciate the edits to the [tag:appcelerator] info and we will follow whatever way the community decides to take it. We just wanted to give some guidelines on how to keep things clear. For example, [tag:alloy] is used by Appcelerator Alloy developers while this tag is about something completely different (see the info). So we want to encourage people to use [tag:appc-alloy] instead. [tag:appcelerator-alloy] is fine as well, but "appc" is a common abbreviation for our company and saves keystrokes.

Comment: Yesterday I ran into a few tag wiki edit suggestions by @Fokke. It seems that both long and short tags are still being maintaned separately: [[tag:appcelerator-alloy]] vs [[tag:appc-alloy]], [[tag:appc-ti]] vs [[tag:appcelerator-titanium]], etc. I also believe that these pairs should be the synonyms of each other. Also, do heed [the comment by Mike McCaughan](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314689/should-we-appcelerate-appc#comment294567_314701) below, linking to http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support .

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'd love for these synonyms to happen. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/appcelerator/info does and should promote the full tags ([tag:appcelerator-titanium]) but shorter ones ([tag:appc-titanium] or even [tag:appc-ti]) are very convenient IF... indeed, they can be made synonyms, which I myself cannot do. We are aware of that product-support faq, we're constantly learning on how to best work with Stack Overflow and fully open for your feedback.

Comment: @Fokke For one, Rene Pot has both sufficient rep and score to suggest a synonym for [tag:appcelerator-titanium]. If you get in touch with the SO staff regarding your product support, they can probably help with the (even) smaller tags for which nobody can suggest a synonym yet. You will also have to agree on which versions to keep as tags (since the synonyms will automatically relocate to the other tag); I assume it would be better to keep the full tags, with the shorter tags automatically being replaced by the full ones.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. What's the best way to get in touch with the SO staff on this?

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen You can use http://stackoverflow.com/contact - once they're done, you should post an answer here so it can be accepted.

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support , the contact link is right there in the final paragraph;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the tags have been re-named to make their meanings more clear.